# jquery code not working( for alert)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I had a problem wirh my jquery code.My code work well except the alert part in IF condition.

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ onSelect: function(dateStr) {
         var url = 'GetExchangeRate';
         var sellingRateValue;
         var buyingRateValue;
         $('#Duedate').val(dateStr);
         $.post(url, { dateToGet: dateStr },
    function(data) {

         var dr = $('#Dollar').val;
         var br = $('#BuyingRate').val;
         var sr = $('#SellingRate').val;
         if ((dr == null || dr.length < 1) && (br == null || br.length < 1) && (sr == null || sr.length < 1)) {
           alert("Please enter the exchage for today.");
            $('#Dollar').val('');
            $('#BuyingRate').val('');
            $('#SellingRate').val('');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#Dollar').val(data.DollarRate);
            $('#BuyingRate').val(data.SellingRate);
            $('#SellingRate').val(data.BuyingRate);

            //alert(data.CurrentDate);


        }
    }, 'json');
     }
     });
```

Here is code part which is not working.

```
if ((dr == null || dr.length < 1) && (br == null || br.length < 1) && (sr == null || sr.length < 1)) {
           alert("Please enter the exchage for today.");
            $('#Dollar').val('');
            $('#BuyingRate').val('');
            $('#SellingRate').val('');
            return false;
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work well in the IF alert part, what do you mean? Does the ELSE part always run?

Comment: Is it throwing any javascript error?

Comment: What do you mean, not working? How doesn't it work? Is an error message given? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Did you alert dr, br, and sr right before the `if`?.... They should **all** be empty strings or null.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
 function(data) {

         var dr = $('#Dollar').val();
         var br = $('#BuyingRate').val();
         var sr = $('#SellingRate').val();
```

with () at the end.

Comment: Let's keep looking!  (Use it with the parentheses anyway)

Comment: @Mik-Mark - You definitely should use the parentheses for .val() (though it does do something w/o them) - http://api.jquery.com/val . Are you using Firebug http://getfirebug.com or some other JS debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not entirely sure what it is that you want to do, the logic may be a bit off. You should apply Sebastian's fix first and possibly rethink the condition for your if statement.

```
if (     (dr == null || dr.length < 1)
      && (br == null || br.length < 1)
      && (sr == null || sr.length < 1)) {

    alert("Please enter the exchage for today.");
    $('#Dollar').val('');
    $('#BuyingRate').val('');
    $('#SellingRate').val('');
    return false;
}
```

The logic of the if means that only reset these fields if all the fields are empty, which doesn't seem to make sense to me. I'm guessing what you want to say is, "reset all of these fields as long as any one of them are empty."

```
if (     (dr == null || dr.length < 1)
      || (br == null || br.length < 1)
      || (sr == null || sr.length < 1)) {
```

**Side note:**

I think you should change your condition to,

```
if (!dr && !br && !sr) {...} // your original code
```

or

```
if (!dr || !br || !sr) {...} // With my fix
```

Comment: I agree.  
@Mik-Mark, the lines inside the condition are resetting the contents of three input elements that you just found all empty in your example.

Comment: @Sebastian - If those elements had no `value` attribute, I guess it would add empty `value` attributes... but that code in and of itself shouldn't cause the if to not trigger.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai, the OP said the alert() part of the IF doesn't trigger. It might as well mean that the if was never true.

Comment: Well of course, but that just means things are working fine. The possibility of some sort of syntax or other error outside that if should be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

First, like Sebastian wrote, you should use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) with parentheses.

Second, try this right before the `if` instead of what you have now:

```
     var dr = "";
     var br = "";
     var sr = "";
```

If the alert pops up now, then you know that it didn't pop up before because not all three of `dr`, `br`, and `sr` are being set to empty strings or `null`. (all three must be "" or `null` for the `if` to trigger).

If the alert still doesn't pop up then you have some other problem outside that `if` statement.

Make sure you look at your variables / code with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).